# Property defined using "server.context-parameters.*" doesn't work on Java EE server

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jboss, spring-boot

We've generated a basic [Spring Boot application](https://github.com/DISID/disid-proofs/tree/master/spring-boot-application-own-configuration) to test some features.

I've [prepared it](https://github.com/DISID/disid-proofs/commit/23db6946fcbff15b7b23fd3d2a02463bfe448bb0) to be deployed on an embedded server and on Java EE servers (Tomcat 7 and JBoss EAP 6.2) without applying any changes.

I've included `server.context-parameters.*` property on [application.properties](https://github.com/DISID/disid-proofs/blob/master/spring-boot-application-own-configuration/src/main/resources/application.properties) file.

If I deploy the application on an embedded server using `java -jar` or `mvn spring-boot:run`, it's working without problems. But, If I deploy the same application on Tomcat 7 or JBoss EAP 6.2, I'm not able to load the context-params correctly.

- Which is the correct way to define context parameters on Spring Boot application deployed on Java EE container without use **web.xml** file?

> You could see all debugging information related with this Spring Boot issue [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/4816)

Comment: I already answered the first question on the spring boot issue (I think). As for the second question, have you tried to define a bean of type `ServletContextInitializer` in your app?

Comment: Thanks for your support! I was trying with `onStartup` method from `SpringBootServletInitializer`... but this solution didn't work on embedded server.  I'm going to add an answer with the final solution. Best regards.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally, I found the following solution thanks to [Stéphane Nicoll](https://stackoverflow.com/users/613628/st%C3%A9phane-nicoll)

`server.context-parameters.*` only works for embedded servers, so to configure context-parameters on Java EE server is necessary to include a `@Bean` of type `ServletContextInitializer` like the following:

```
@Bean
public ServletContextInitializer contextInitializer() {
    return new ServletContextInitializer() {

        @Override
        public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext)
                throws ServletException {
                servletContext.setInitParameter("dummy.type","on-context-parameters");
        }
    };
}
```